# PyQt5 - Move button actions inside a separate thread using QThread()

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qthread

I am new to building GUIs in Python and even more to multithreaded programming, hence, I apologise in advance if my vocabulary/terminology is not accurate enough.

I have the following code that builds a GUI using PyQt5.

```
    import PyQt5
    import automation_main
    from PyQt5.QtWdigets import *
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *

    class Window(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
            self.setWindowTite('Test')
            self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500)
            self.UiComponents() #calling the UI components method
            self.UiWidgets() #calling the UI widgets method
            self.show()

        def UiComponents(self):
            button1 = QPushButton('Hello', parent=self) 
            button1.setGeometry(120, 670, 150, 50)
            button1.clicked.connect(self.clickme) #button1 calls the clickme() method

        def UiWidgets(self):

            # here I define a textbox where the user inputs a year
            self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
            self.textbox.setGeometry(185, 140, 450, 40)
            self.textbox.returnPressed.connect(self.entered)

            # here I define a QlineEdit where the user chooses a month
            self.combobox = QComboBox(self)
            self.combobox.setGeometry(185, 255, 450, 40)
            options = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
            self.combobox.setEditable(True)
            self.combobox.addItems(options)
            line_edit = self.combobox.lineEdit()
            line_edit.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            line_edit.setReadOnly(True)
            self.combobox.activated[str].connect(self.selected)

        def entered(self):
            #defines self.entered_text that correponds to the user input in the QLineEdit()
            self.entered_text = int(self.textbox.text())
    
        def selected(self, text):
            #defines self.selected_text that correponds to the user selection in theQComboBox()
            self.selected_text = text

        #Finally

        def clickme(self):
            # uses functions self.entered_text and self.selected_text inside the function block
            year_loc = automation_main.main(self.selected_text, self.entered_text)
```

What I have attempted:

1. I have created a Worker class and included the clickme() function in it with generic

```
    class Worker(QObject):

        finished = pyqtSignal()
        progress = pyqtSignal(int)
        def clickme(x, y):
            year_loc = automation_main.main(x, y)
```

2. I created a method in class Window() that creates a thread

```
    def createWrokerThread(self):
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.start()
```

Then I called this method inside the class Window() constructor namely

```
    class Window(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            ...
            self.createWorkerThread()
            ...
```

3. I changed the button action in UiComponents():

```
    def UiComponents(self):
        button1 = QPushButton('Hello', parent=self) 
        button1.setGeometry(120, 670, 150, 50)
        button1.clicked.connect(self.worker.clickme(self.entered_text, self.selected_text)
```

Problem: I get an error saying that 'Window' has no attribute 'entered_text'

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The error says exactly what it means: at the point where `UiComponents` is called, `self.entered_text` and `self.selected_text` have not been created yet; you probably create those members later on, but unfortunately you didn't provide enough code to understand what you actually do, so please take your time and provide a valid [mre] we can work with.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read through. I have edited my post with further code. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: That `button1.clicked` is wrong: connection arguments expect a *callable*, while you're directly executing the function. Use lambdas or partials.

Comment: @musicamante, I am looking to execute ```clickme()``` in the worker thread once the user clicks on button1, not sure how to use lambdas there?

Comment: Sorry but your question is too broad and vague (and we still don't have a valid MRE or context to understand how your "automation" works). There are many ways to deal with threading and communicating between them (assuming communication *is* required). For all we know, you could just create the other thread in the main window's `clickme()` function, by simply providing them as arguments of the `Worker` and overriding the `__init__`. I strongly suggest you to take your time to read more about threading and how Qt deals with them, using simpler cases that allow you to understand how they work.

Comment: It is okay, thank you, I managed to figure out a better way of doing it, although it still doesn't work.
I created a method for when ```button1``` is clicked by writing ```button1.clicked.connect(self.btn1_clicked)```.
Then in ```def btn1_clicked(self):``` I started the thread by ```self.worked_thread.start()``` and invoked ```clickme()``` by writing ```self.worker.clickme(self.selected_text, self.entered_text)```

Comment: Although now I get the following error ```Type Error: clickme() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given```

Comment: `def clickme(self, x, y):`.